# Turning a Json table into a standard df

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I have a json array table that I am inserting into notebook such as

```
Table
{"id":"v100",signal:"2017-10-02 03:30:00",mode:"online"}
{"id":"v100",signal:"2017-10-02 06:30:00",mode:"online"}
{"id":"v400",signal:"2017-10-03 03:30:00",mode:"online"}
{"id":"v400",signal:"2017-10-04 05:30:00",mode:"offline"}
```

Without column names and just those headers and values in each row.

How can I transform this into a dataframe that has column names for:

```
id          | signal       | mode
v100   2017-10-02 03:30:00   online
v100   2017-10-02 06:30:00   online
v400   2017-10-02 03:30:00   online
v400   2017-10-02 05:30:00   offline
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use the pandas `read_json()` function

Comment: have you tried using [pandas.read_json()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list comprehension with convert json to dictionaries and then pass it to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
import ast, json

print (df)
                                               Table
0  {"id":"v100","signal":"2017-10-02 03:30:00","m...
1  {"id":"v100","signal":"2017-10-02 06:30:00","m...
2  {"id":"v400","signal":"2017-10-03 03:30:00","m...
3  {"id":"v400","signal":"2017-10-04 05:30:00","m...


df = pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(x) for x in df['Table']])
#alternative
#df = pd.DataFrame([json.loads(x) for x in df['Table']])
print (df)
     id               signal     mode
0  v100  2017-10-02 03:30:00   online
1  v100  2017-10-02 06:30:00   online
2  v400  2017-10-03 03:30:00   online
3  v400  2017-10-04 05:30:00  offline
```

Or if posible use:

```
df = pd.read_json(file, lines=True)
```

Comment: I am getting error of malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x11d21e0f0> using the pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(x) for x in df['Table']]) method and an error of Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 48 (char 47) for the second method. What am I doing wrong? @jezrael

Comment: @Chris90 - Nothing, only data are mess :( there are misisng `""` I guess

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\""}{ print $4 " " $6 " " $8; }' myTable.txt
```

The table line etc. is trivial.